# Why won't \marginpar wrap it's text?

Tags: latex, word-wrap, miktex

I'm using miktex 2.8 on Windows. For some reason, the `\marginpar` command has stopped working. It used to work as expected, but not the lines will not wrap. I have set `marginparwidth` to `1in` and still the lines will not wrap, they just go right off the page (or right into the text for margin pars on the odd pages). If I change `marginparwidth` to something smaller, I see the text move, so I think the value is being recognized, but I can't figure out what changed so that the text is not wrapping.

Comment: can you post a minimal example please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the problem was \usepackage{pdfsync}. Evidently this is the old way to do PDF synchronization. The new way is to add "-synctex=-1" to the command for pdfTex. Using the synctex switch for pdflatex does not screw with the marginpar command, but using the pdfsync package does. Weird.